# Linux and memory buff/cache and disk storage

Tags: linux, rhel, memory, disk, cache

I want to ask question about the memory buff/cache

lets say we have Linux machine with disk , and some application that wrote data to disk /var/data

from my understanding when application wrote data to disk then this data will saved also in memory cache

for some time , and after X time application data will removed from memory cache

is it possible to force the specific data to be saved on memory cache and not on the disk?

the reason for my question - is because we want fast read/write and disks are very slow regarding that

Comment: Do you mean you're fine with the data never hitting the disk at all? In other words, are you fine with losing the data on reboot?

Comment: If your disks are too slow, consider switching to SSDs

Comment: Can you please clarify which cache you are referring to? To me, 'memory cache' usually means the caches on the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> saved on memory cache

There is no such thing really. You start from this **buff/cache**:

```
]# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              7           0           3           0           3           6
Swap:             0           0           0
```

This gives the amount of RAM currently used as buffer or cache. The kernel does this exactly because disks are slow, and there is often (as shown) enough RAM.

If you want to reserve a part of RAM for certain files, you can put them onto a RAM disk (`mount -t tmpfs ...`). But then you have to remember to copy them back to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding about how the memory heirarchy works. The heirarchy goes, from closest to the CPU/fastest to slowest:

CPU register > Cache memory > RAM/main memory > Disk

The cache memory is in between the CPU and main memory and is faster to access than the main memory. Typically, chunks of nearby data (i.e. copies of blocks of address ranges) are copied into the cache when a memory location is accessed. Then, the next time a memory location is accessed, the cache is checked first, to see if the data is already there and time can be saved by not having to access main memory.

So, I think your question doesn't quite make sense. There is typically no intermediate storage or cache between the main memory and disk. Data that is currently in use is stored in RAM, and that is the most efficient way to store and access it. If you want to save it for later, after the machine is turned off, you copy it to disk (because that's your only option). If you want to access the data now and quickly, you don't want to touch the disk, unless you have to.

I am not aware of any means of easily overriding the cache memory management and storing something to the cache, but explicitly not to RAM. There are generally very good and efficient systems already in place to manage memory caching.

Also, I don't believe data gets removed from the cache memory after X amount of time. Typically, it gets pushed out by more recent data that the CPU wants to access.

Comment: The OP is referring to the disk cache (in RAM), not the on-CPU cache(s).

Comment: @StephenKitt well, I'd say the question is unclear then. When someone says 'memory cache' to me, that means the caches on the CPU ...